# Conocer el número de argumentos sin argc

Tags: c

este es mi código, funciona correcto y todo bien:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
    int tokens;
    for(tokens = 0; tokens < argc; tokens++){
        if(argv[tokens][0] == '-')
           printf("opcion: %s\n", argv[tokens]+1);
        else
            printf("argumento %d: %s\n", tokens, argv [tokens]);
    }
    exit (0);
}
```

El problema lo encuentro cuando me piden lo siguiente:
Suponga que no dispone del argumento argc en la función principal, de modo que no se conoce el número de agumentos que el usuario introdujo en la líonea de comando. Modifique el programa para que realice el mismo trabajo sin utilizar argc.

He tratado de usar otra variable como "n" y pedirle al usuario que nos digite cuántos argumentos va a utilizar, pero el programa me marca error de code. Espero que puedan ayudarme o si fueran tan amables, decirme cómo puedo buscar información para hacerlo, porque no encuentro información por ninguna parte.

Answer (score 4):

Podés encontrar referencias del lenguaje C en español en [cppreference](https://es.cppreference.com/w/c/language). En particular sobre la función main [acá](https://es.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).

Como ves, ahí mismo te dice:

> El valor de argv[argc] está garantizado que será ​0​.

Esto significa que para conocer `argc` basta con recorrer los `argv[i]` desde `i=0` hasta que `argv[i]==0`.

Así está bien:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

        int numero_args = 0;

        for (int i=0; argv[i]; i++)
                numero_args++;

        printf("argc calculado: %d\n", numero_args);
        printf("argc real: %d\n", argc);

        return 0;
}
```

Saludos.